# Swift: How do you pass information to a view controller underneath the current one?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have two view controllers, HomeViewController, and SecondViewController, which is pushed on top of HomeViewController at the top of the stack. I have a segue from HomeVC to SecondVC by means of 'Show'. I understand how to pass information from SecondVC to HomeVC - using the prepare for segue method using identifiers. But I do not have a segue from SecondVC to HomeVC, as it is embedded in a navigation controller. How would I pass information, for example a string, from SecondVC back to HomeVC upon popping the SecondVC from the navigation stack?

Comment: If you are passing a reference value from Home to Second, then there is no need, it would be done automatically. If its a Non reference Value (Like a Struct instead of a Class) you will need to create a new segue from second to home and do the same you did the first time.

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios you do not need to create a new Segue you just override "prepareForSegue", intercept the existing Segue and pass the value type ("non reference" you called it), like a struct to the SecondViewController

Comment: Awesome @BrianOgden, Yeah I was writing Will I was moving, momentary forgot value type name vs reference type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a `ViewModel` from the HomeViewController to the SecondViewController, what you do is give your Segue an Identifier and then override prepareForSegue in your HomeViewController:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        if segue.identifier == "mySegueIdentifier" {

            if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
                destination.aViewModel = aViewModel;

            }
        }
    }
```

In your SecondViewController you need to declare the ViewModel:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var aViewModel: AViewModel?
    //rest of code
}
```

And create a ViewModel, use a struct type:

```
struct AViewModel
{
    let AValueIWantToPassAround: String
    let AnotherValueIWantToPassAround: Int
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I needed help in doing it the other way round, i.e, from SecondViewController back to HomeViewController.

Comment: @aayushi_2303 That is a bad design decision, why would a child view need to pass information back to its parent, you should have an API, if the child view controller changes something, you should persist that and then the parent view controller refreshes aka checks the persistence when it is shown again

Comment: But the quick, dirty and long term unmaintainable way is to use a reference type like @MargoNicolasPalacios mentions in his comment to your question

Comment: @aayushi_2303 I will not show you how to do that because I would be teaching you a very bad software developer habit